# Identify Accounts WITHOUT Specific TeamMemberRole?

Tags: soql, query, account, account-teams

For an output project using S-Docs I need to be able run a soql to identify when an Account does NOT have a `TeamMemberRole` of "Vice President of Sales" (anti-join) which will output a "Sales VP: N/A" result.  Associated with this is another soql to identify when the `TeamMemberRole` of "Vice President of Sales" does exist which then outputs a "Sales VP: John Doe" result.

I originally tried, for the anti-join:

```
SELECT accountid, COUNT(teammemberrole) FROM accountteammember 
WHERE accountid in (
    SELECT account__c from Account_Plan__c 
    WHERE Account__r.id = '{{!Account_Plan__c.Account__r.id}}'
)
AND teammemberrole IN ('Vice President of Sales') 
GROUP BY accountid HAVING COUNT(teammemberrole)=0
```

but then found the `HAVING` clause does not work with anti-join.

I next tried for the anti-join:

```
SELECT accountid, accountaccesslevel FROM accountteammember 
WHERE accountid in 
    (select account__c from Account_Plan__c 
     where Account__r.id = '{{!Account_Plan__c.Account__r.id}}')
     and teammemberrole not in ('Vice President of Sales') 
GROUP BY accountid, accountaccesslevel
```

This works for scenarios when there:

1. are one or more teammemberroles associated and none of them are "Vice President of Sales"; output is "Sales VP: NA"
2. is only one teammemberrole associated and it is "Vice President of Sales"; outputs nothing and the 2nd soql outputs "Sales VP: John Doe"

But does NOT work for scenarios where there:

3. are NO teammemberroles associated then nothing will display; nothing is output but I need to have "Sales VP: NA" outputed
4. are two or more teammemberroles associated and one of them is "Vice President of Sales". gives output "Sales VP: NA" from first soql and outputs "Sales VP: John Doe" from second soql

How can I get scenarios 3 & 4 successfully?

Here is the entire code, including S-Docs code for both soqls and output:

```
<!--{{!
<LineItemsSOQL>
<class>table2</class>
<soql>
select accountid, accountaccesslevel from accountteammember 
where accountid in 
    (select account__c from Account_Plan__c 
     where Account__r.id = '{{!Account_Plan__c.Account__r.id}}')
     and teammemberrole not in ('Vice President of Sales') 
group by accountid, accountaccesslevel
</soql>
<column prefix="<span class=gry>Sales VP: N/A" postfix="</span>"     
 nullprefix="Sales VP: N/A" substitute="(Read/Write,&nbsp;),
 (Edit,&nbsp;)">accountaccesslevel</column>
</LineItemsSOQL>
}}-->
<!--{{!
<LineItemsSOQL>
<class>table2</class>
<soql>
select teammemberrole, user.name from accountteammember 
where accountid in 
(select account__c from Account_Plan__c where Account__r.id = '{{!Account_Plan__c.Account__r.id}}')
and teammemberrole in ('Vice President of Sales')
</soql>
<column mergenext="true" prefix="<span class=gry>" postfix=":</span>" 
substitute="Vice President of Sales,Sales VP" nullprefix="<span 
class=gry>Sales VP: N/A" nullpostfix=":</span>">teammemberrole</column>
<column>User.name</column>        
</LineItemsSOQL>
}}-->
```

Comment: I think `select ... From account where id in (select account__c from account_plan__c where id = :planId) and id not in (select accountid from accountteammember where teammemberrole = 'Vice President of Sales')`... Not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you are using an [inner join](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join), ***not an [anti-join](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Anti_Join)***. You have identified the correct tool for the job, but not used it! If you just need `Account` data, the following will work just fine for you:

**Account Query**

```
SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id NOT IN (
    SELECT AccountId FROM AccountTeamMember
    WHERE TeamMemberRole = 'Vice President of Sales'
)
```

Comment: Adrian,  Thank you.  This put me on the right path and with a little tweaking works perfectly. SELECT Id, IsDeleted FROM Account WHERE Id NOT IN (
    SELECT AccountId FROM AccountTeamMember
    WHERE TeamMemberRole = 'Vice President of Sales'
) and ID ='{{!Account_Plan__c.Account__r.id}}'

Comment: Glad you got it working!